# Create/update/delete data on database

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to using react, redux, and I have the following question. I have two Apps, an API, and a front-end App with react and redux. How can I create/update/delete a record? I know that I have to create a pure function in order to update my store, but where can I create/update/delete? I'm pretty sure that I don't have to modify my data using my dispatch (my actions), so I think I have to update my database record using reducer, but does this make my functions impure?

Comment: You do this in Actions, using something like redux-thunk http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Answer (score 0):

Reducers are only used as pure functions in order to manipulate the store based on actions that action creator dispatch.
Take a look at the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware, take a look at this [example provided](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition)